# i have a problem with Android studio AVD and apt-get

Tags: release-loki, apt, libreoffice, android-studio

so first. I've installed Android Studio and its working fine, except when I try to create AVD virtual device it says:

```
An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details.
```

i found a solution to use 
    sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
at first it did not work it brought out

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it
```

so i decided to search for a solution and i found a few soultions from here [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)
So i tried the command again to fix my android studio

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

then it brought out:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
 libobasis5.3-calc : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-en-us-base : Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                           Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-en-us-calc : Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                           Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-en-us-math : Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                           Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-en-us-res : Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-extension-javascript-script-provider : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                                                     Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-extension-mediawiki-publisher : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                                              Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-filter-data : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-gnome-integration : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-graphicfilter : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-images : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-kde-integration : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                                Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-librelogo : Depends: libobasis5.3-writer (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libobasis5.3-writer (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-ogltrans : Depends: libobasis5.3-impress (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libobasis5.3-impress (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-ooofonts : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-pyuno : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis5.3-xsltfilter : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                           Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.3-base : Depends: libreoffice5.3 (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libreoffice5.3 (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libobasis5.3-base (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libobasis5.3-base (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.3-calc : Depends: libreoffice5.3 (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libreoffice5.3 (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.3-dict-es : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.3 (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.3 (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.3-dict-fr : Depends: libobasis5.3-core (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libobasis5.3-core (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.3 (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.3 (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.3-en-us : Depends: libreoffice5.3 (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libreoffice5.3 (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us-writer (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libobasis5.3-en-us-writer (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.3-impress : Depends: libreoffice5.3 (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.3 (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libobasis5.3-impress (>= 5.3.1.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libobasis5.3-impress (<= 5.3.1.2-2) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried my android studio AVD again and it still brought out the same error.
I tried the command a recommended by the terminal

```
apt-get -f install
```

and got:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

switched to root and tried it again and got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 libido3-0.1-0
  switchboard-plug-gcc-bluetooth
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libobasis5.3-calc libobasis5.3-en-us-base libobasis5.3-en-us-calc libobasis5.3-en-us-math
  libobasis5.3-en-us-res libobasis5.3-extension-javascript-script-provider
  libobasis5.3-extension-mediawiki-publisher libobasis5.3-filter-data libobasis5.3-gnome-integration
  libobasis5.3-graphicfilter libobasis5.3-images libobasis5.3-kde-integration libobasis5.3-librelogo
  libobasis5.3-ogltrans libobasis5.3-ooofonts libobasis5.3-pyuno libobasis5.3-xsltfilter
  libreoffice5.3-base libreoffice5.3-calc libreoffice5.3-dict-es libreoffice5.3-dict-fr
  libreoffice5.3-en-us libreoffice5.3-impress
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 23 to remove and 102 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

tried over and over again. but no progress.
I don't know what to do right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have some `dpkg`, `apt` or similar process running. You have to kill them first (or do simply a reboot).

If even this does not help you might have to remove the lockfile manually: `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. No solutions worked for me except Run as Administrator. Simple solution, but at last this solved the error.